A movie which a man hides from German soldiers during Second World War in his house
I am looking for a movie which I watched about 15 years ago. It was about during Second World War somewhere in Europe a man was hiding in house from Nazi soldiers. In house was so big that it was something like castle. Soldiers were trying to kill him but because he knew his house very well he was killing them one by one instead.
It was made in France most probably I am not sure. I were watching with Russian translation. None of the actors were well-known I think.
Does anyone know this movie?

Welcome to Movies & TV! When did you see this? How old was it? What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.

I watched the movie 15 years ago. It was made in France most probably I am not sure. I were watching with Russian translation. None of the actors were well-known I think

This is The Old Gun aka Vengeance One by One (Le vieux fusil) from 1975.
Plot:
In Montauban 1944, during the German retreat from France, Julien Dandieu, an ageing embittered surgeon in the local hospital is frightened by the German army entering Montauban, Dandieu asks his friend Francois to drive his wife and his daughter to the remote village where he owns a château.
One week later, Dandieu sets off to meet them for the weekend, but the Germans have now occupied the village. He finds that all the villagers have been herded into the church and shot. In the château, now occupied by the Germans, he finds his daughter shot and his wife immolated by a flame-thrower.
Dandieu decides to kill as many Germans as possible to avenge his family, he takes an old shotgun he used as a child while hunting with his father and sabotages the château's bridge before he starts to kill them one by one, taking advantage of his knowledge of the secret passages within the château.
